# Main character is a cyborg mercenary, possibly fights demons

Tags: story-identification, books, cyborg, demons

Looking for a book that may have been part of a series, possibly based on an RPG, where the main character is a cyborg mercenary, who has been significantly reduced in height because of his cyborg surgery and I believe ends up fighting demons?

Definitely pre-2000

Comment: The only story I can recall involving demons and reduced height heroes is the origin story of Puck from Marvel Comics Alpha Flight. Puck was originally 6'6" tall, and battled a demon. It tried to possess him, but he contained it, which left him compressed down to 3'6" tall.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found anything about the reduction in height, but the "[Demon Download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Future)" series features cyborgs hunting demons and it was based on the Dark Future game by Games Workshop. However, it looks like the main protagonist is female, Jessamyn 'Krokodil' Bonney, as introduced in *[Krokodil Tears](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852835605)* in 1993.

[image: Cover image] [image: Krokodil Tears cover]